# How to see proxy configuration on mac (not UI) to use corporate git

Tags: linux, git, macos, proxy

How can I see in mac the proxy configuration on my machine ( Not the ui) 
My friend have problem to use our corporate git 
when He do `git clone` he get proxy error but in my mac **I was able to clone this repo**. in the UI both configuration are the same
https://kb.netgear.com/25191/Configuring-TCP-IP-and-Proxy-Settings-on-Mac-OSX

And maybe we miss something else...

we use in the command line

`export http_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.corp:8080`

and also

`https_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.corp:8080`

without success, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
curl -v google.co.uk
```

That will show you the proxy server and proxy port you are using
Then you can compare with your friends output.